# Rails - Linking attributes from two models in a new/create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

This being my first app I'm still a little confused as to how to go about in accomplishing what I want to get done. In short I'd like to create albums, each having their own tracklist. So essentially I'd have an albums model and a tracklist model with their associations as follows:

```
# album.rb
  has_one :tracklist

# tracklist
  belongs_to :album
```

This would be their attributes

```
create_table "albums", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "artist"
  t.datetime "release_date"
  t.string   "label"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "tracklists", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "track_name"
  t.time     "duration"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The default way to create an attribute for a record is done through a single text field but as you may know, albums have more than one track, which would require multiple text fields to list the tracks. By default I was planning on allowing the user to be presented with 12 vacant fields to add/subtract tracks if needed (a rough example found in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h5npj6t/)**).

I've began looking into nested model forms but the railscast(s) and tutorials currently out there seem way to complex for a beginner who wants something a little simpler done. Can someone give me an idea on how I would structure my controllers and views with the given information while incorporating this javascript functionality?

Comment: Carl, let me write an answer for you using Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nested**

The relevant resources for this is (for future reference):

- [Nested model forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

The way that Ryan achieves what you're looking for is somewhat dated, and I'd hope to give you some ideas on how to do it with Ajax. Firstly, let me explain the process, and then I'll explain the best way I've found it to work:

> 1. Create a form in the "traditional" way
> 2. You have some sort of "modular" way to create extra fields
> 3. You create a mechanism to add those fields to your form

This will give you the ability to append fields as you wish. Ryan Bates does things in a slightly dated way - using javascript to append pre-rendered fields. This is very constrictive, as it prevents you from being able to add as many fields as you want

--

Here's what we do (we use Ajax. Sorry, the resource we had for this has disappeared from the net):

```
#app/models/album.rb
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tracks

   def self.build
      album = self.new
      album.tracks.build
   end
end

#app/models/track.rb
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
end

#config/routes.rb
resources :albums do
  get :add_field, on: :collection
end

#app/controllers/albums_controller.rb
class AlbumbsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @album = Album.build
   end

   def add_field
      @album = Album.build
      render "form", layout: false
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to create the following views:

```
#app/views/albums/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= render partial: "fields", locals: { f: f } %>
   <%= link_to "Add Field", add_field_path, method: :get, remote: true, id: "add" %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/albums/_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :tracks, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |r| %> #-> child_index is the most important part
   <%= r.text_field :title %>
<% end %>

#app/views/albums/form.html.erb
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: "fields", locals: { f: f } %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, this will give you the ability to do the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#add", function(data){
   $("#form").append(data);
});
```

Comment: Got an error in my routes file: `b:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) get: add_field, on: :collection`

Comment: Ended up getting `undefined method name`. Can we move this to a chat?

Comment: Yep - do you want to to initialize it or me?

Comment: Sure is there a way to start one in this thread or do I have to manually create it via: chat.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: It normally appears if you write enough comments - let me go and get a sandwich, then I'll come and create a chat for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60095/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-rich-peck).

Comment: You available to chat?

Answer (score -1):

It's a good idea to keep things as simple as possible.

1. I'd recommend having Albums and Tracks (instead of track lists) as your models, with an album having many tracks. A track list is just a collection of tracks, which should each be their own record.
2. On the client side, I'd recommend first setting up separate forms for each action you would want to take. So rather than creating a nested form for albums, have a single form that allows you create a single track for an album.
3. Controller / View wise I would use pretty much what a scaffold gives you for album, and have the show action render a list of tracks for that album and a form to create a new track for that album.

Hopefully that helps get you off to a good start!

Comment: This is great advice but it still leaves me wondering how to create multiple fields for tracks.

Comment: If you're set on being able to upload a bunch of track data in one form, than a nested form is probably the way to go. If it's not truly necessary, just allow one track to be added / edited at a time with a single track form.